NestJS: Instance of INestApplication does not have setBaseViewsDir?
I would just like to set up a template engine locally, as my workflow now is rendering the tempalte and having to go to my aws-s3 bucket to see the results.
In the NestJS docs the hace an example using:
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(
    AppModule,
  );

  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
  app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));
  app.setViewEngine('hbs');

  await app.listen(process.env.PORT ?? 3000);
}
bootstrap();

By creating this instance const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
But I am using INestApplication and when check the instance none of those methods exist? Isn't NestJS built on top of Express? How would you use templates locally so I can do logs in my templates etc, so I don't have to go to my aws-bucket after every save.
Thanks!

Can you explain the question in more robust way, as i cannot even comprehend what you want to know?

@Seti I think my question should be how do you use the expressAdapter in a INestApplication app.

returned app being INestApplication is already connected with expressAdapter, i mean - app.use will be directly using .use from express and so on.

But thats because you used .create<NestExpressApplication> which tells nest to use express underneath. If you want to use some direct methods from express, you can use (app as NestExpressApplication) [example: `(app as NestExpressApplication).disable('x-powered-by`)` that disables express ,,x-powered-by'' header for responses.
